# Last-Child Margin-Bottom not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Basically i have a margin bottom one all of the 'row' divs. with a margin-bottom: 0 on the last div, but it doesnt seem to be working. I am working with HTML and SCSS.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif; }

.left-sidebar {
  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red; }

.main-body {
  margin-left: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 50px; }
.main-body a {
  margin-bottom: 50px; }
.main-body a .row {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  margin-bottom: 50px; }
.main-body a .row.one {
  border: 10px solid red; }
.main-body a .row.two {
  border: 10px solid red; }
.main-body a .row.three {
  border: 10px solid red; }
```

```html
<div class="left-sidebar"> 

</div>

<div class="main-body">

  <a href="#"><div class="row one"></div></a>
  <a href="#"><div class="row two"></div></a>
  <a href="#"><div class="row three"></div></a>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't see that `margin-bottom: 0` anywhere in your code. Does "last div" mean `.main-body` or `.row.three`? What is the desired behavior?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, having `<div>` inside `<a>` is putting a bottle inside water, where I mean, having block level elements inside inline elements is a crime.

You have already defined `margin`. You should add the following CSS:

```
.main-body a .row.three {
  margin-bottom: -50px; }
```

Or, you need something like this:

```
.main-body a:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0; }
```

**Snippet**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif; }

.left-sidebar {
  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red; }

.main-body {
  margin-left: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 50px; }
.main-body a {
  margin-bottom: 50px; }
.main-body a .row {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  margin-bottom: 50px; }
.main-body a .row.one {
  border: 10px solid red; }
.main-body a .row.two {
  border: 10px solid red; }
.main-body a .row.three {
  border: 10px solid red; }
.main-body a:last-child, .main-body a .row.three {
  margin-bottom: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="left-sidebar"> 

</div>

<div class="main-body">

  <a href="#"><div class="row one"></div></a>
  <a href="#"><div class="row two"></div></a>
  <a href="#"><div class="row three"></div></a>

</div>
```

You need to note that your `.main-body` has also a `padding` of `50px`. If you need to reduce it, you can also add this:

```
.main-body {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Placing block-level elements inside inline boxes can be problematic, but I wouldn't say it's a crime.

Comment: @Oriol Ha ha.. You don't understand what a HTML guy thinks.